# Setting up a Docker-Compose that will set up a Rails dev enviroment for local development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I’m new to Docker, I think I’m getting it down for server setup using docker, however I want to use Docker so non-engineer staff in my company can more easily setup a Rails dev enviroment, database, installing libraries on the ruby and javascript end, that kind of thing.

I can do it using Docker, however it requires getting into the docker engine and tweaking databases and what not which I feel is asking a lot for a non-engineer persons and doesn’t lessen there burden as just setting them up natively.

I’ve looked around on guides to setup Rails environments but they all tend to have a lot of work required to get everything up and running, I wish to have a more easier way of just fire up terminal and go to the project folder, smack 1 or 2 commands in and have it all done, is there any guide or example setup to do something like this?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/ you can use this

Comment: oh... I've missed that one, thanks.

Comment: That link has moved to https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/